# Saving figure with Julia PlotlyJS does not use layout options

Tags: plotly, julia

I"m trying to save figures made with Plotly in Julia. I'm attempting to make the plot have a square aspect ratio, but when saving the figure it reverts to the default aspect ratio.

For example,

```
xVals = 0:1:10
zVals = ones(10,10)
axis_template = attr(range = [0,10], autorange = false)
lay = Layout(autosize=false,xaxis=axis_template,yaxis=axis_template,width=700,height=700)
trace = PlotlyJS.heatmap(x= xVals ,y=xVals,z = zVals)
p = PlotlyJS.plot(trace,lay)
PlotlyJS.savefig(p,"test.png")
```

This doesn't save the figure with a square aspect ratio, and savefig seems to ignore most of the content in Layout. Additionally, I'm not sure setting the width and height is the correct way to get the correct aspect ratio, but nothing else I've tried works (ie aspect_ratio=:equal just does nothing).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `width` and `height` parameters of the `savefig()` function to define the size of the plot that is saved:

```
savefig(p, img_path, width=700, height=700)
```

Use help (`?`) to have a look at the `savefig` function's signature.

```
help?> savefig
search: savefig StackOverflowError

  savefig(
      io::IO,
      p::Plot;
      width::Union{Nothing,Int}=nothing,
      height::Union{Nothing,Int}=nothing,
      scale::Union{Nothing,Real}=nothing,
      format::String="png"
  )

  Save a plot p to the io stream io. They keyword argument format determines the type of data written to the figure and must be one of png, jpeg, webp, svg, pdf, eps, json,
  or html. scale sets the image scale. width and height set the dimensions, in pixels. Defaults are taken from p.layout, or supplied by plotly
```